Magisk Update gives error please try again with *unpatched* boot image
I went to a phone repair shop to change my Samsung s9+ IMEI number. They installed the magisk and warned me if I do a factory reset or similar things, the changes they did will be erased. Also, I can't use bank apps because the phone is rooted.
Therefore, I searched and learned that using some modules of Magisk made it possible to use those apps. However, I needed to update the Magisk since that version was old (v22) and needed a newer version to get those modules. I updated Magisk by clicking update on the app.
But after updating it to v28, the main page of Magisk became like this:

And when I click to update and select direct install it gives this error:

What can I do to fix this?
Also after searching for a solution, I realized that I updated Magisk in hidden mode, the problem occurred because of that maybe.
